# C# Array contains partial

Tags: c#

How to find whether a string array contains some part of string?
I have array like this

```
String[] stringArray = new [] { "abc@gmail.com", "cde@yahoo.com", "@gmail.com" };
string str = "coure06@gmail.com"

if (stringArray.Any(x => x.Contains(str)))
{
    //this if condition is never true
}
```

i want to run this if block when str contains a string thats completely or part of any of array's Item.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Assuming you've got LINQ available:

```
bool partialMatch = stringArray.Any(x => str.Contains(x));
```

Even without LINQ it's easy:

```
bool partialMatch = Array.Exists(stringArray, x => str.Contains(x));
```

or using C# 2:

```
bool partialMatch = Array.Exists(stringArray,
      delegate(string x) { return str.Contains(x)); });
```

If you're using C# 1 then you probably have to do it the hard way :)

Comment: Jon's code works fine here. You're missing something from your example.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for if a particular string in your array contains just "@gmail.com" instead of "abc@gmail.com" you have a couple of options.

On the input side, there are a variety of questions here on SO which will point you in the direction you need to go to validate that your input is a valid email address.

If you can only check on the back end, I'd do something like:

```
emailStr = "@gmail.com";
if(str.Contains(emailStr) && str.length == emailStr.length)
{
  //your processing here
}
```

You can also use Regex matching, but I'm not nearly familiar enough with that to tell you what pattern you'd need.

If you're looking for just anything containing "@gmail.com", Jon's answer is your best bets.